# Replace all spaces between certain characters with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace all spaces with certain words with the help of regex

from

```
<h3>Chinese Fan Palms</h3>
```

to

```
<h3>ChinesehoneyFanhoneyPalms</h3>
```

My Replace word is **honey**

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please include your current regex, it helps others to understand what you want to achieve. So you need to replace spaces between *certain characters*... What are these "characters"? Do mean between tags `<h3>` ... `</h3>` or certain words `Chinese` ... `Palms` ?

Comment: i suspect this isn't really what you want, but is what you asked for  `/ /honey/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

Find:`(^<h3>|\G).*?\K`   note!  After `\K` there is a single space ...
Replace with:`Honey`

This regex only effects if the line starts with `<h3>` ....